# Also Accent Mark is where on Keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout

How to, On a Dell keyboard, make a upside down question Mark. Have tried nothing. Looking @ keyboard. Seems a Hobby for a Hobfessional.

Comment: I presume by your question, you have not attempted to figure this out, going as far as not even providing us the character you actually want to use.  Update your question to at least include that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ALT+168 to produce this symbol: ¿

Press and hold the ALT key then type 168 on the number pad. Num Lock does not have to be activated to use this method.