# How do I type a Trademark Symbol?

Tags: keyboard

How do I place a trademark symbol after a company name?

Comment: What has your research shown?

Comment: Which model of typewriter do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as was to [your previous question about `¿`](https://superuser.com/questions/1032688/also-accent-mark-is-where-on-keyboard), only using the right character code from the [character map](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codealt.html), for the trademark symbol.

Alt+0153 = `™`

[Here's the link to a character map again](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codealt.html), for you to consult for other symbols (if needed).